# R: Recommended Method of Downloading Discontinued R Packages

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am interested in trying to download the following R package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osmar/index.html

When I open this page, it tells me that this R package has been removed.

**My Question:** I was wondering if there is a recommended way of downloading packages in such situations.

Doing some reading, I came across two methods:

**Method 1:**

```
require(devtools)
install_version("osmar", version = "1.1-7", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org")
```

**Method 2:**

```
install.packages("path/to/osmar_1.1-7.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Is there an ideal way to proceed in this situation?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-005/RJ-2013-005.pdf
- https://rpubs.com/JesperHybel/673341

Comment: In this case, I would probably get version 1.1-8 from r-forge (i.e. `install.packages("osmar", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`) as there may be bug fixes that weren't included in the archived CRAN version. OSMAR is a pretty old package - when you run `library(osmar)` you get the warning `The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning this package will retire shortly.`; perhaps it might be worth looking for a more up-to-date alternative...

Comment: On the other hand, if you are interested in downloading and working with osm data, then `{osmdata}` package might be solution.